# Why is ActionBarSherlock not responding?

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock, listener

I'm a noob to android and I am using ActionBarSherlock's menu bar to access menus.  Everything works fine on android APIs lower than API 11, but for any API 11 and Above the menu bar/menu items are unresponsive.  The menu items highlight when I click them, but they don't execute.  It's almost as if the menu items have lost their listener is there a setting that I forgot to implement? any help is greatly appreciated.

My Code:

```
//My Sherlock wrapper 
ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);

//OnCreate
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
mSherlock.setContentView(R.layout.main);

 //Menu Methods
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case 1:   // id from the xml file
            Intent i = new Intent("com.bmoney.GSCC.OPTIONS");
            startActivity(i);
            return true;   // we handled the click, dont pass it up the chain

        case 2:   // id from the xml file
            Intent i2 = new Intent("com.bmoney.GSCC.PREFS");
            startActivity(i2);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mSherlock.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    } 


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { //<-- has Sherlock Menu Import

        menu.add(0,1,0,"Preferences").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_example).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add(0,2,0,"Help").setIcon(R.drawable.info).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add an OnMenuItemClickListener to your menu items when you add them in onCreateOptionsMenu. Then add the OnMenuItemSelected method and implement the code you have in onOptionItemSelected in the OnMenuItemSelected method.  So you should have...

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  

     // Code from inside onoptionItemSelected
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess, your import for `MenuItem` is for `android.view.MenuItem`, and not the Sherlock equivalent.

If so, I suggest that:

- You add `@Override` to `onOptionsItemSelected()`
- You delete all `android.view.*` imports, then re-add them as Sherlock ones (e.g., via Ctrl-Shift-O in Eclipse)
- You consolidate your two `onCreateOptionsMenu()` methods, using the one with the Sherlock import

Comment: Thanks for responding.  My menuitem impot was already the sherlock equivalent. I followed your suggestions, but when i consolidate my OnCreateOptionsMenu the menu items don't appear in the menu bar.  Please check my edits.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @B.Money: Beyond Corey Scott's answer, nothing leaps to mind. Here is a sample app with a working action bar: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that you need to "return true" when you handle the menu event.

Also, you might find if you restructure your method to the following that you will have an easier time reading and maintaining it.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId())
{
    case R.id.options:   // id from the xml file
        Intent i = new Intent("com.bmoney.GSCC.OPTIONS");
        startActivity(i);
        return true;   // we handled the click, dont pass it up the chain

    case R.id.prefs:   // id from the xml file
        Intent i = new Intent("com.bmoney.GSCC.PREFS");
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
}

return false;
```

}